# Why am I getting no such file error when using "mammoth" to convert a simple .docx file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mammoth

My code is as below.  The contents of the file is a simple "hello world" I have the hello.docx file in the same folder I am calling this mammoth function.

**Error result:** fatal Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './hello.docx'

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using this in my express node route

```js
mammoth.extractRawText({path: "./hello.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var text = result.value; // The raw text 
        console.log(text);
        // var messages = result.messages;
    })
    .done();
```

Comment: Try providing a full path

Comment: It seems clear by the error displayed that the directory or file cannot be read.How are you uploading your file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear by the error displayed that the directory or file cannot be read. *How are you uploading your file?* If you are uploading your docx file using multer, you need to provide a reference to the file uploaded inside the path or buffer option as such:

```
mammoth.extractRawText({buffer: variable_that_holds_the_file.buffer})
    .then(function(result){
        var text = result.value; // The raw text 
        console.log(text);

    })
    .done();
```

Else, you need to revise the path since it may not be correct.
To test this, use `__dirname` and or `__filename` in your console.log inside multer to see where your path is.

Answer (score 0):

use below code it might help you. it worked for me.

```
const mammoth = require("mammoth");
const path = require("path");

let filePath = path.join(__dirname,'./sampledocxfile.docx');

mammoth.extractRawText({path: filePath})
    .then(function(result){
        var html = result.value; 
        var messages = result.messages; 
        console.log(html);

    })
    .done();
```